# Escaping JSON string in Sightly

Tags: sightly

I have the following Sightly template:

```
<body>
  <script type="application/json" id="test">
    [
        {
            "url": "${test}"
        }
    ]
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to escape the value of 'test' using JSON style escaping. Unfortunately, [using context='scriptString'](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context) escapes a dash as '\-', which is [invalid JSON](http://json.org).

How can I use JSON style escaping on this value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `context='unsafe'` to write JSON like this:

```
${test @ context='unsafe'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sightly uses OWASP [Encode#forJavascript()](http://owasp-java-encoder.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1/core/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html#forJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) for the scriptString context. It seems to be a bug or a missing documentation about escaping dashes.

For URLs you can use context='uri'. For plain text you can use context='text'.